# Use splat operator in multidimensional list index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have the list

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6]]
```

and I have an index that I want to use to access an element of this list.

```
index = [1,2]
```

I want to use something like

```
a[*index] = 9
```

to mean `a[index[0]][index[1]] = 9`, but this doesn't work and neither does `a[**index] = 9`. Is there a similar way to do this without having a chain of index calls?

I would like a method to do this without using any libraries that must be imported.

Comment: You should look into `numpy` if you want to do this type of indexing

Comment: Or you can create your own `Matrix` class

Comment: Or you can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Answer (score 3):

First of all `a[c, d, e]` is equivalent to `a[(c, d, e)]` which is equivalent to `a.__getitem__((c, d, e))`. Note the double parentheses. Any `__getitem__` implementation that wants to play nice with the Python data model always expects exactly one (explicit) argument.

That's why unpacking values from `index` inside the `[]` does not make much sense. `a[*index]` will give you a `SyntaxError` and `a.__getitem__(*index)` gives you a `TypeError` (because you are providing too many arguments).

Standard Python lists expect integer arguments to `__getitem__`, but `numpy` supports indexing with tuples (a numpy array still only takes exactly one argument for `__getitem__`, but it's allowed to be a tuple).

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> a[(1,2)]
6
```

Of course, you can omit the parentheses, because

```
>>> a[1,2]
6
```

is exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), which is part of the standard library:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], 
...      [4, 5, 6]]
>>> index = [1, 2]

>>> import functools, operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.getitem, index, a)
6
```

Or, you can write your own class that supports that kind of multi-dimensional indexing:

```
import functools, operator

class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, index, self._lst)


a = Matrix([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]])
index = [1, 2]

print(a[index])  # -> 6
```

Otherwise, this is not possible using just lists and without loops or other functions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing there is no simple way to do this without any libraries.

Comment: @dylnan: well, you could use a simple for-loop if you don't want to use any external module. But if you want to use lists only, then no: there is no way

Comment: How would I use the first method to redefine an element of `a` in place?

Comment: @dylnan: well, if you want a one-liner, then it would be `functools.reduce(operator.getitem, index[:-1], a)[index[-1]] = <new-value>`. But if you need such functionality, then using your own class is the best way to go. Python is a high-level language, take advantage of it!